# Type hinting in interfaces

Tags: php, types, interface, type-hinting

I want to do repositories interfaces. At the moment I have two entities: `User` and `Payment`. So I want to do repositories for these entities: `UsersRepository` and `PaymentsRepository`.

Every repository in project will have a common abilities, for example: `findOne`, `find`, `save`, `delete`. So I think I should create a common repository with which other repositories will be extended `RepositoryInterface`.

```
<?php
interface UsersRepository extends RepositoryInterface {}
```

My services will depend on these interfaces. So how I can type-hint, that `UsersRepository::findOne` will return `User` entity?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the return type of the function like this:

```
<?php
interface UsersRepository extends RepositoryInterface {
    function findOne() : User;
}
```

Since generics are **not** available in php you wouldn't be able to do:

```
<?php
 interface RepositoryInterface<T> {
    function findOne() : T;
    function save(T record);
 }

 interface UsersRepository extends RepositoryInterface<User> {
    function findOne() : User;
 }
```

So you'll just have to specify the return type for each method in each repo

Comment: Nowadays generics in php is an RFC under discussion https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics